# Android-Unable to focus custom EditText in Xamarin ListView

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, android-edittext

**Description**

I have written custom view in Xamarin. And implemented the view design in renderer with EditText.

When I try to focus the EditText in ListView ItemTemplate, Keyboard not showing in android platform.

Without ListView, custom Entry focus works fine.

**Steps to Reproduce**

Run the sample
Focus listview Item EditText. Focus not set.

Focus outside custom view EditText. See focus set.

**Basic Information**

Version with issue: 4.8.0.1451

Platform Target Frameworks:

Android: Samsung A6 plus.

OS : 10

```
Mainpage.xaml.cs

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public string[] Items { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Items = new string[] { "Item1" };
            BindingContext = this;
        }
    }

    public class CustomizedView : View
    {

    }

MainPage.xaml

..
        <local:CustomizedView/>
        
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" RowHeight="200" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <local:CustomizedView/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>


CustomRenderer.cs

..

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomizedView), typeof(CustomViewRenderer))]

namespace CustomView.Droid
{
    public class CustomViewRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(e.NewElement != null)
            {
                FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(Forms.Context);

                EditText editText = new EditText(Context);
                editText.Text = "Text";
                editText.SetPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

                frameLayout.AddView(editText);

                SetNativeControl(frameLayout);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Run the sample Focus listview Item EditText. Focus not set.

You can delete **FrameLayout** from CustomViewRenderer, it will works fine in ListView, get focus.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {                
            //FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(Forms.Context);
            EditText editText = new EditText(Context);              
            editText.Text = "Text";
            editText.SetPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);              
            //frameLayout.AddView(editText);              
            SetNativeControl(editText);
            
        }
    }
```

But I also suggest you can use custom Control using contentview, you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview#create-a-custom-control

Comment: I need to add some other combined views in my custom view. So, I need to add FrameLayout in my custom view.

So, please suggest any other solution with FrameLayout.

Comment: @MuneeshKumar you can replace the ListView with a CollectionView and that seems to have fixed the problem.Also, the CollectionView doesn't have a HasUnevenRows property, so that will have to be removed and it doesn't use cells, so ForceUpdateSize() method will also have to be removed.

Comment: @MuneeshKumar My reply can solve your problem? Please return any update. If it is beneficial to you, please mark my reply as answer, it will help others.